# Return resulting json from github API on html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/Microsoft",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
           $('#result').html(res)
        }
    });

})

</script>
```

Whenever I try to see the result on my browser it just shows an empty blank page.

I just need to return the API result and show it on html.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using network monitor available in devtools of your browser to inspect the server's response? Maybe use `$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(res))` instead of your line. To analyse the issue, insert `console.log( res );` right before that line injecting the result into HTML element just to make sure this callback is ever invoked. And see the console for probably showing warning regarding CORS issue.

Comment: Thank You! That was it, also, excuse me, just a question, do you know how can I format that response? I mean, just an idea, can I put every json item into a different div?

Comment: Formatting: don't use a `<div>`, but a `<pre>` might help with that, though it still might require to pretty-print the JSON as a string: `$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(res, null, '\t'));`.

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AJAX callback makes `res` an object. When you using `.html()` the argument must be a string. If you want to see the object represented on the page, use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/Microsoft",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
       $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(res))
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd stick with `.text()` instead of `.html()` just to make sure any contained `<` isn't parsed as HTML ... it's performing better, too.